# Did Miriam Criticize Moshe for being Haughty?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, behaalotcha-parsha, miriam

[Avos Derebbi Nassan 9:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D%27Rabbi_Natan.9?lang=bi) says that Miriam criticized Moshe for being haughty by divorcing his wife.

> אבל הוא מפני שדעתו גסה עליו פירש הוא מאצל אשתו
>
> But Moses, because he is so arrogant, separated from his wife.

This is actually pretty logical considering that the [Passuk immediately afterwards](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.12.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0) says:

> והאיש משה ענו [עניו] מאד מכל האדם אשר על־פני האדמה
>
> Now Moses was a very humble man, more so than any other man on earth.

However, [Avos Derebbi Nassan then proceeds](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D%27Rabbi_Natan.9?lang=bi) to walk back the claim that she criticized Moshe for being haughty somewhat by saying that they didn't judge him as being certainly haughty, merely as being possibly haughty.

> ולא היו דנין אותו בודאי אלא בספק ספק שדעתו גסה עליו ספק שאין דעתו גסה עליו.

While this is a logical reading of the Pesukim in the end of Beha'alosecha, it is quite a striking claim. Does anyone else concur with this interpretation?

Even better would be if anyone can find someone who says this without walking it back halfway.

Comment: The Avos Drav Nosson doesn't seem to be retracting it seems to be clarifying.

Comment: @schmerel I agree with you but it reads pretty strange. It says that she accused him definitively without any qualification and then says afterwards that she only meant it as a Safek (although she didn't use words to imply that).

Comment: Are you sure that דעתו גסה means, haughty? Not such a usual phrase. See Taanis 20a.

Answer (score 0):

The first quotation: אבל הוא etc. is a direct quote from אהרון.

אהרן אמר: אלי היה דבור ולא פירשתי מאצל אשתי ואף אבותינו הראשונים היה דבור עליהם ולא
פרשו מאצל נשותיהן אבל הוא מפני שדעתו גסה עליו פירש הוא מאצל אשתו

The next quotation: ולא היו דנין etc. is a comment/clarification of אהרון's words.

This does not seem to be backtracking. אהרון is quoted and his quote is then qualified.